# Variadic template using lambdas : error with g++ but running with clang++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

While playing with variadic templates, classes, functions and lambdas, ([from here](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/))  I found that following code is running with `clang++` while *not* running with `g++` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class... F>
struct overload_set : F... 
{
  overload_set(F... f) : F(f)... {}  
};
template <class... F>
auto overload(F... f) 
{
  return overload_set<F...>(f...);   
}
int main()
{
    auto func = overload (
        [](int &val) { val *= 2; }, 
        [](string &arg) { arg += arg; }, 
        [](char &c) { c = 'x'; }
        );
    int val = 10;
    string str = "stackoverflow";
    char ch = 's';
    cout << val << " : " << str << " : " << ch << endl;
    func(val);
    func(str);
    func(ch);
    cout << val << " : " << str << " : " << ch << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For `clang` : [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79511e4b5c99263a)

For `g++`   : [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04dd847cdd6f68c7)

`g++` is giving ambiguous `operator()` for `func(val)`, `func(str)` and `func(c)`. I think the `operator()` must not be ambiguous, as each one is having different arguments.

What's the problem with `g++`?

Comment: @Niall: it's not really about the lambdas or even variadic templates; even given the simplest `struct` deriving from bases `B1`, `B2`... with different `operator()(X&)` functions, g++ needs `using B1::operator(); using B2::operator();` (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bc933418b5ff82f)).

Comment: @TonyD. I'm thinking it is a clang bug - some test indicates there is a difference here in how clang resolves functions from the base classes vs how it resolves the call operator.

Comment: @Niall gotcha, clang resolves `x()` differently from `x.operator()()`.

Comment: This issue was already addressed [here](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/lambda-hackery-overloading-sfinae-and-copyrights/comment-page-1/#comment-12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has little to do with lambdas, variadic templates, operators or any advanced C++1{xy} stuff. Let's simplify:

```
struct foo
{
    void func(int&){}
};
struct bar
{
    void func(char&){}
};

struct test : foo, bar {};

int main()
{
    test t;
    int i = 1;
    char c = 'a';
    t.func(i);
    t.func(c);
}
```

This fails to compile in either `g++` or `clang++`. Which is a good thing too, because that's how the language is specified to work.

If we change `func` to `operator()`, `g++` continues to reject the program but `clang++` either accepts or rejects it, depending on how the operator is called:

```
 t.operator()(c); // rejected
 t(c);            // accepted
```

Which looks like a clang bug to me.

In order to make the code above compile, a very small change is needed:

```
struct test : foo, bar {
  using foo::func;
  using bar::func;
};
```

Now I have no idea how to make pack expansion work in the using directive, or if it's indeed possible. But there's a workaround:

```
template <class... F> struct overload_set;

template <> struct overload_set<> {};

template <class F> struct overload_set<F> : F {
  using F::operator();
  overload_set(F f) : F(f) {}
};

template <class F, class... Fs>
struct overload_set<F, Fs...> : F, overload_set<Fs...>
{
  overload_set(F f, Fs... fs) : F(f), overload_set<Fs...>(fs...) {}
  using F::operator();
  using overload_set<Fs...>::operator();
};
```

With this change your code compiles with both `g++` and `clang++`.

Comment: There is a link from the OP's linked blog post that is pretty much this workaround. The blog mentions it as a "industrial-strength version", [link here](https://github.com/picanumber/CODEine/blob/master/lambda_utils.h)

Comment: @Niall The industrial version is the one I've seen Yakk among others use (there are variations on the base template, the number of specializations and the use of perfect forwarding)